# How is this indefinite integral a holomorphic function?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, analytic-number-theory

In an analytic number theory textbook we derived the formula
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \{x\}x^{-s-1}\mathrm{dx}$$

and the textbook says, that the integral on the right side converges uniformly on any compact subset of $\{s\mid \mathrm{Re}(s)>0\}$ and is a holomorphic function. But there is no reasoning why any of this should be true, so it can't be that hard..

That the Integral converges uniformyl means what $$f_n(s)=\int_1^n\{x\}x^{-s-1}\mathrm{dx}$$ is converging uniformly as a function in $s$. And it is no problem to see that this is true on any compact sets on the right half-plane. If I can prove now that each of these $f_n(s)$ are holomorphic function, combined with the compact convergence this implies that $$\int_1^\infty \{x\}x^{-s-1}\mathrm{dx}$$ is a holomorphic function.  However I was not able to prove that these $f_n(s)$ are holomorphic.

After I failed to apply any theorems on this, I tried the definition
$$\lim_{s\to s_0}\frac{f_n(s)-f_n(s_0)}{s-s_0}= \lim_{s\to s_0}\int_1^n\{x\} \frac{x^{-s-1}-x^{-s_0-1}}{s-s_0}\mathrm{dx}$$

At this point if I were able to interchange the Integral and the limit, I would get

$$\lim_{s\to s_0}\frac{f_n(s)-f_n(s_0)}{s-s_0} =\int_1^n\{x\} \lim_{s\to s_0}\frac{x^{-s-1}-x^{-s_0-1}}{s-s_0}\mathrm{dx} = \int_1^n\{x\} (-x^{-s_0-1}\ln(x))\mathrm{dx}$$

and since $0\leq\{x\}\leq 1$ this last integral exists what implies that the limit on the left side exists what finishes the prove.

However, I am unable to acutally prove that this interchange of the limit is valid.

I would appreciate any help on this. Or maybe anyone has an other "better" argument why this integral in the first equation is a holomorphic function, maybe I dont even need all this reasoning.

Comment: partition the interval $[1, n]$ into $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$, ..., $[n-1,n]$. On each of those intervals, the function ${x}$ can be replaced by a continuous function without changing the integral, e.g. on $[2,3]$, we have $x-2$. Now use the Leibniz integral rule from complex analysis.

Comment: it is a basic result in complex analysis (and one should not study advanced topics like RZ without a very good understanding of basic CA) that if $f(t,z)$ is jointly continuous and holomorphic in $z$ then $\int_{\gamma}f(t,z)dt$ is holomorphic in $z$ for any (finite) curve $\gamma$ that is contained in the $t$ domain of $f$; applying this with the curve being $[1,n]$ gives the required result; the continuation from that to the infinite curve (interval) $[1, \infty)$ follows as noted by local uniform convergence in $z$ which is true here (in general one needs some extra assumptions on $f(t,z)$)

Comment: Morera and Fubini easily imply the basic result above (and one can relax the joint continuity in $(t,z)$ to conditions that allow Fubini to be applied to the integral $\int_{\Delta}\int_{\gamma}f(t,z)dtdz$ where $\Delta$ is a triangle contained in the $z$ domain and st $(\gamma, \Delta)$ are in the joint domain

Comment: And, in line with @Conrad's apt comments, if ${\partial\over \partial z}f(t,z)$ is uniformly continuous, then the differentiation passes inside the integral. All these things take advantage of the fact that Cauchy theory uses _integrals_, even to express derivatives, and integrals are better behaved than derivatives. :)

Comment: Also, maybe you meant "improper integral", rather than "indefinite integral"... (for contemporary English use).